# his very first novel vs his first novel

Tags: word-usage

In a reading comprehension exercise for my students there is a sentence: "What was it like to become famous with your **very first novel**?" Does it mean that the author wrote more than two books? ... *I´ve read the answers on the related topic, but they didn´t help me in this particular case.*

Comment: It in an emphasis.  While "very first novel" means "first novel", the "very" emphasizes the "first".  I have never heard something like "very second novel".  But I have heard something like "very last novel".

Comment: While intending no denigration of the answer you have selected (Centaurus consistently provides cogent answers & commentary) by officially selecting the first (and only) answer posted, you have 1) made a "choice" without benefit of comparison; and 2) disincentivized any further community involvement. Whereas, by postponing official selection you avail yourself of the community and the opportunity to make a choice based upon comparison

Comment: I´m sorry, I´m learning how it works here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here "very" is used as an adverb. It's just for emphasis and doesn't suggest the author has written one, two or many novels.

> very (adv) to a great degree
>   —used to emphasize the exactness of a description [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/very)
>
> - "the very same thing happened to me."
> - "He has damaged his very own car."
>
> very (adv) - used as an intensive emphasizing superlatives or stressing identity or oppositeness.
>
> - "the very best thing"; "in the very same place" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/very)